# Angular NodeJS Requests Automatically Change Request URLs During Produciton/Development

Tags: node.js, angular

What is the best practice for changing all HTTTP requests from http://localhost:3000/get/info
to http://mydomainname.com/get/info when I build for production and deploy live to my domain?

And then back to localhost when I am adding more features and testing?

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides us with environment.ts and environment.prod.ts files, you can utilize them like this-

```
  // environment.ts
  export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/get/info'  
};
 // environment.prod.ts
  export const environment = {
  production: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://mydomainname.com/get/info'  
};
```

ng build --prod will use base url from environment.prod.ts, and locally base url from environment.ts will be used.

You can import environment file where you need to make api calls in your application, and use baseUrl from it.